# nodejs - log to console stdio and file using only core modules

Tags: node.js, logging, process, stream, console

My application is simple and I want to avoid using a logging library like Winston. I need to log the output to both the console, and to file. I found a few tutorials on how to do this using a child process, such as [this](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-stream-pipe/), but I can't find anything that leverages the main process stdio, like process.stdout and process.stdin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to solving this was recognizing that process.stdio is a writable stream whereas a child process's stdio using the child_process module is a readable stream (thanks to [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93/)). Therefore I needed to create both a readable and writable file stream, and pipe the readable stream out to process.stdio. You could probably simplify this even further with a duplex stream, but for noobs like myself, this is a straightforward and easy to read approach.

```
const { Console } = require("console")
    , process = require("process")
    , path = require("path")
    , fs = require('fs');

// Define the file paths to log to
const outputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, './stdout.log');
const errorFilePath = path.join(__dirname, './stderr.log');

// Create the empty files synchronously to guarantee it exists prior to stream creation. 
// Change flag to 'w' to overwrite rather than append.
fs.closeSync(fs.openSync(outputFilePath, 'a+'));
fs.closeSync(fs.openSync(errorFilePath, 'a+'));

// Create a writable file stream for both stdout and stderr
const fileWriterOut = fs.createWriteStream(outputFilePath);
const fileWriterErr = fs.createWriteStream(errorFilePath);

// Create a new Console object using the file writers
const Logger = new Console({ stdout: fileWriterOut, stderr: fileWriterErr });

// Create readable file streams for process.stdio to consume
const fileReaderOut = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, './stdout.log'));
const fileReaderErr = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, './stderr.log'));


// Pipe out the file reader into process stdio
fileReaderOut.pipe(process.stdout);
fileReaderErr.pipe(process.stderr);

// Test the new logger
Logger.log("Logger initialized");

// Export
module.exports = Logger;
```